# Changing the text of a button according to whether media is playing or paused?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video

My code partially works. When I click play it changes to paused, but when I click pause right after it just stays as pause and doesn't change back to play?

```
var playOrPause = function (id, button) {
var pp = document.getElementById(id);
    if(pp.paused) {
        button.textContent = 'Play';
    } else if(!pp.paused) {
        button.textContent = 'Pause';
    }
};
```

I just figured out my problem. I coded one of my event listeners wrong lol Thank you guys for the help!!

Comment: Why not `if(pp.paused) {
        button.textContent = 'Play';
    } else {
        button.textContent = 'Pause';
    }`

Comment: I tried that, it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Share complete code including markup and how you are invoking the function..

Comment: It won't let me upload the whole thing. It says that it's not code and that I need to add more details

Comment: I figured it out, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.player_audio').click(function() {if (this.paused == false) { this.pause();
  alert('music paused'); } else { this.play();alert('music playing');}});
```

This will help you

Comment: var playOrPause = function (id, button) {
var pp = document.getElementById(id);
    if(pp.paused) {
        button.textContent = 'Play';
    } else if(pp.play) {
        button.textContent = 'Pause';
    }
};

Comment: All time your condition was going to elseif part . even play or pause . so the condition is not working please check you if statement

Comment: Could you please put you code in jsfiddle so that i can solve it

Comment: Never used jsfiddle. Just set up an account and put the code in but how do i shareit?

Comment: Go to your account -> click your public fiddles -> paste you code. save it. copy the url and send it to me